# Android: How to access a Pending Intent in a different activity?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-context

I am setting up `AlarmManager` with a `PendingIntent` in activity A.
Then I would like to be able to call `cancel()` on the same `PendingIntent` from a different activity B.

The Android documentation says the following:

> "If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid, and can thus call cancel() to remove it."

Is it possible to store a `PendingIntent` in a database 
and retrieve it from a different activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not creating your PendingIntent in a dynamic way, then you just need to create it the same way.

I would recommend creating a singleton that will create and deliver your PendingIntent. That way, you could call something like this from anywhere in your application:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntentHelper.getInstance().buildPendingIntent();
am.cancel(pi);
```

Comment: @sfrantini I have a similar use case here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61161676/android-cancel-alarm-and-pendingintent-in-different-activity  Any ideas on how to fix?